# A simple(?) Analytical Geometry Question (Ellipse)

Tags: geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple(?) Analytical Geometry Question (Ellipse) my teacher can't solve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192517/a-simple-analytical-geometry-question-ellipse-my-teacher-cant-solve)

Here's the story:

I am a high school student who absolutely loves math. So I took a university level mathematics course that is renowned throughout our school for being extremely rigorous and is feared by most. Last week we had our first lesson, and this quarter we'll be focusing on analytical geometry. Our teacher, known at our school for being the best mathematician, gave us this homework:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/78587548@N06/7944911996/in/photostream Find the cartesian equation of the ellipse

This probably is extremely easy for you guys, but don't forget this was our very first lesson. I couldn't solve it and today in class I found out nobody actually solved this. But what really shocked me, our teacher couldn't solve this either! He actually had no clue at all, he stared at it for like 20 minutes, and tried like FP=PQ but he couldn't solve it! So my question to you guys is, what is the solution (not only the answers but also explanation). I want to assure you guys that this is not our homework, and I want to know the answer as my 'smart' teacher doesn't know it either and I feel as if the only forum where people could answer these questions without a problem is this one